# TextBox OnTextChanged not firing

Tags: c#, jquery, textbox, calendar, datepicker

I have an asp textbox that I have hooked up to a jQuery calendar control on the document ready like so

```
$('#txtPromoPrcStrt').datepick({
   dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
   onSelect: function(selectedDate) { txtPromoPrcStrt_TextChanged(); }
});
```

Where the `txtPromoPrcStrt_TextChanged` function sets some default values for other boxes.  The problem is, the OnTextChanged event of the TextBox doesn't fire after I select a date from the DatePicker, but it will fire if I go into the textbox and enter values from the keyboard.

1) Why is this happening?

2) How can I get an event to fire when the user selects a date from the date picker?

Comment: any errors in the console error log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually trigger an event like so:

```
$('#txtPromoPrcStrt').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thank you very much that works great.  Any idea why an event is not fired when a value is selected from the datepicker?  Is it because no keystrokes are made inside the textbox?

Comment: The change event is fired when the user changes the textbox; the datepicker just sets the value. Simply setting the value in javascript does not automatically fire the event - the browser is doing that for you when you interact with it.